# Load parquet data from Google cloud storage to BigQuery using spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How can I load parquet data to spark from Google cloud storage and save it to BigQuery?

Comment: Pretty well lol.

Answer (score 2):

To load data into Spark from Google Cloud Storage:

`df=spark.read.parquet("gs://<path to parquet file>")`

And you can write after doing necessary transformations in the similar way(add gs to the start of the file name)

You can parquet load data from cloud storage in parquet to BigQuery , by following the below link:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet

Comment: We need to also do some transformation on data before writing to BQ. Hence we are looking at using spark.

Comment: If this resolves your query, please mark it as answer